# Incorrect autocomplete, $this->getRequest in Controller class is referencing to Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Request

Tags: symfony, phpstorm

I'm trying out PhpStorm, but I'm having problem with the autocomplete of Request object when returned from `$this->getRequest()` of the Controller class.

The documentation always shows it's from `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Request` hence no autocomplete. It should really be from `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`. does anybody here has encountered this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it with phpdoc, though there is a [known issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-9303) about it.